# Connect python with h2o that runs in docker, but ipv4 for h2o changes

Tags: docker, ip, connect, h2o

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to run *h2o* in docker and then use python to connect to it.
I have folder with:
  model-generator folder in which I have the python script and Dockerfile to build an image
  h2o-start folder in which I have h2o.jar file and Dockerfile to start that jar
  docker-compose.yml file with:

```
version: "3"
services:
   h2o-start:
      image: milanpanic2/h2o-start
      build: 
         context: ./h2o-start
      restart: always
   model-generator:
      image: milanpanic2/model-generator
      build:
         context: ./model-generator
      restart: always
```

My python script contains:

```
import h2o   

h2o.connect(ip='172.19.0.3', port='54321')
```

When I run docker-compose up it gives me an error that python can't connect, because there isn't anything on 172.19.0.3

Dockerfile for python

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install > --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt 
EXPOSE 80 
ENV NAME World 
CMD ["python", "passhash.py"]
```

Dockerfile for h2o

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD h2o.jar h2o.jar
EXPOSE 54321 EXPOSE 54322
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "h2o.jar"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to docker container from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931857/how-to-connect-to-docker-container-from-localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start container exposing port 54321: add to your `h2o-start:` in docker-compose file:

```
ports: 
  - "54321:54321"
  - "54322:54322"
```

Comment: Now, I just redirect h2o.connect(ip='127.0.0.1', port='54321'?

Comment: Great! :) Please, as it works, upvote or accept my answer, please

Comment: I connect the python to 127.0.0.1:54321 where h2o server is running, but it can't find the data.csv file, can you help ?

Comment: I'll try, but first, can you tell me what's `data.csv` file?

Comment: It is a file containing data to build the machine learning model off of

Comment: The H2O that is running in the container and redirects it on localhost:54321 can't see users/desktop/data.csv path.
I found something with volumes in docker, is it a good idead ?

Comment: Try to mount volume for that file. Save it in your host and share it with both containers with `--volume` option.